# Update meta_value in wp_postmeta using API

Tags: rest-api, post-meta

I am trying to update a specific meta_key field using an API. meta_key name is _yoast_seo_redirect. it contains a redirect URL which we give in post options within wordpress.

[image]

What I am trying to achieve is, whenever someone hit the url like :

http://yoursite.com/wp-json/post_info/post?id=59&meta_value=www.google.com

it should update the post_id : 59 with meta_value : www.google.com

Write now, I am getting json error while trying to achieve this :

```
[
{
code: "json_no_route",
message: "No route was found matching the URL and request method"
}
]
```

Here is my function using which I am trying to achieve :

```
function get_post_details ($params)
{
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $meta_value = $_GET['meta_value'];  

    if(update_post_meta( $id, '_yoast_wpseo_redirect', $meta_value ))
    {
        $post['status'] = 'Successfully Updated';
        $post['flag'] = '1';
    }
    else
    {
        $post['status'] = 'Error';
        $post['flag'] = '0';    
    }

    if( empty( $post ) ){
        return null;
    }

    return $post;
}

 // Register the rest route here.

add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
    register_rest_route( 'post_info', 'post',array(

            'methods'  => 'GET',
            'callback' => 'get_post_details'

        ));

});
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank You !

Comment: And where exactly is your code failing you?

Comment: @kero I have updated the question with error I am getting. Thank You

Answer (score 1):

I can't really recreate the error. Are you sure the script is properly loaded?

```
function get_post_details ($params)
{
    return rest_ensure_response( 'Hello World, this is the WordPress REST API' );
}

// Register the rest route here.
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
    register_rest_route( 'post_info', 'post',array(
            'methods'  => 'GET',
            'callback' => 'get_post_details'
        ));
});
```

This gave me the expected response - so the route was correctly registered at

```
http://www.example.com/wp-json/post_info/post
```

As for the arguments, as [suggested in the REST API docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/routes-and-endpoints/), you should use `$params` instead of `$_GET`. Changing this and adding `$post = array();` (so the variable is properly declared), made your code work on my local machine. You should probably check first, if these values are even set, also

```
function get_post_details ($params)
{
    $id = $params['id'];
    $meta_value = $params['meta_value'];

    $post = array();

    if(update_post_meta( $id, '_yoast_wpseo_redirect', $meta_value ))
    {
        $post['status'] = 'Successfully Updated';
        $post['flag'] = '1';
    }
    else
    {
        $post['status'] = 'Error';
        $post['flag'] = '0';
    }

    if( empty( $post ) ){
        return null;
    }

    return $post;
}

// Register the rest route here.
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
    register_rest_route( 'post_info', 'post',array(
            'methods'  => 'GET',
            'callback' => 'get_post_details'
        ));
});
```

and the route

```
http://www.example.com/wp-json/post_info/post?id=21&meta_value=https://www.google.com
```

[**If you don't have pretty permalinks enabled, the route may look different!**](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/routes-and-endpoints/#routes-vs-endpoints)

Comment: Using this url, http://www.example.com/?rest_route=/wp/v2/posts/59
I am able to get the post info. But even in this, I am not seeing meta_key as _yoast_seo_redirect. 

Do I need to check for meta_keys registered using 3rd party plugins?

http://www.example.com/?rest_route=/wp/v2/posts/59

Comment: @AnkitPandey These aren't your custom routes, but those of WP core. You should be able to use those [as described in the corresponding API doc](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/posts/#schema-meta)